# LLVM cpp backend, does it replace c backend?

Tags: c++, c, llvm, clang

My question is regarding the CPP backend, does it serve the same purposes as the C backend?
The C backend was one of my favorite LLVM features, and I'm very upset it was removed.

Whats the real differences?
I' most appreciative of any help.

Reference:
[The LLVM 3.1 Release Notes](http://llvm.org/releases/3.1/docs/ReleaseNotes.html#whatsnew)
"The C backend has been removed ..."

Comment: Hm... I don't really use a lot of C anymore (there's the occasional third-party library, but...), but the llvm website doesn't mention anything about removing C? Arguably, the llvm website sucks, so not finding anything there is quite normal :-) They should take a look at the gcc manual website... :-)

Comment: @ChristianStieber: Just to clarify, I'm not referring to compiling C through a fronted.  I'm talking about compiling LLVM Assembly to C, set by --march, as you would specify a machine target.  Really great way to get a lower-lever understanding, without having to read pure assembly.  In LLVM  < 3.1, you could even recompile the output again, it really was an awesome feature.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The CPP backend creates LLVM API calls to create an AST that represent the equivalent of the LLVM assembly. You can try the CPP backend at http://llvm.org/demo/ by selecting the "LLVM C++ API code" *Target*.

The C backend creates C code that execute the semantics of the LLVM assembly.

They are fundamentally different.

Comment: The C backend has been removed from the latest LLVM. No one was maintaining it and it was becoming increasingly non-functional.

Comment: @RichardPennington thanks for confirming. unmaintained software is no good :)

Comment: Can the CPP backend be recompiled?  Does that now add new LLVM library dependencies to a final binary?  Does a CPP recompile still depend on originally included libraries?